# Python dynamically load tuple/list from settings file

Tags: python, list, dynamic, nested-lists

I would like to load a list/tuple dynamically from a settings file.

I need to write a crawler that crawls a website, but I want to be made aware of files that were found, rather than pages.

I allow the user to specify such file types in `settings.py` file, like this:

```
# Document Types during crawling
textFiles = ['.doc', '.docx', '.log', '.msg', '.pages', '.rtf', '.txt', '.wpd', '.wps']
dataFiles = ['.csv', '.dat', '.efx', '.gbr', '.key', '.pps', '.ppt', '.pptx', '.sdf', '.tax2010', '.vcf', '.xml']
audioFiles = ['.3g2','.3gp','.asf','.asx','.avi','.flv','.mov','.mp4','.mpg','.rm','.swf','.vob','.wmv']


#What lists would you like to use ?
fileLists = ['textFiles', 'dataFiles', 'audioFiles']
```

I import my settings file in the `crawler.py`

I use `beautifulsoup` module to find links from the HTML content and process as follows:

```
for item in soup.find_all("a"):
            # we dont want some of them because it is just a link to the current page or the startpage
            if item['href'] in dontWantList:
                continue

            #check if link is a file based on the fileLists from the settings
            urlpath = urlparse.urlparse(item['href']).path
            ext = os.path.splitext(urlpath)[1]
            file = False
            for list in settings.fileLists:
                if ext in settings.list:
                    file = True
                    #found file link
                    if self.verbose:
                        messenger("Found a file of type: %s" % ext, Colors.PURPLE)
                    if ext not in fileLinks:
                        fileLinks.append(item['href'])

            #Only add the link if it is not a file
            if file is not True:
                links.append(item['href'])
            else:
                #Do not add the file to the other lists
                continue
```

The following code segment throws error:

```
 for list in settings.fileLists:
                if ext in settings.list:
```

clearly because python thinks that settings.list is a list.

Is there anyway to tell python to dynamically look in the lists from the settings file?

Comment: Don't name your own variables `list`, you shadow the built-in. Also, using a `set` would make membership testing more efficient.

Comment: Where does `settings.list` come from?

Comment: Thank you. I have amended my naming as well. My IDE wasn't really happy about that either :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is instead of:

```
if ext in settings.list:
```

You need

```
ext_list = getattr(settings, list)
if ext in ext_list:
```

EDIT:
I agree with jonrsharpe on the list thing, so I renamed it in my code